# Error: making pointer from integer in C

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, int, mpi

I am trying to write a c program thatwill check in a parallel way if a random vector is sorted or not.

```
 int isSorted(int size, int array[]) {

 .........
  int *sub_rand_nums = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_elements_per_proc);

  int orden = isSorted(num_elements_per_proc, sub_rand_nums);

// Gather all partial results to all the processes

  int *sub_ordens = NULL;
  if (my_rank == 0) {
    int  *sub_ordens = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * my_size);
  }

if (a == 0) {
    int orden = isSorted(sub_ordens, my_size);
  }




}
```

Can somebody help to solve teh problem with my code? It gives me the error of

```
passing argument 1 of ‘isSorted’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      orden = isSorted(sub_ordens, my_size);
```

and

```
passing argument 2 of ‘isSorted’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      orden = isSorted(sub_ordens, my_size);
```

Comment: `sub_ordens` is an `int *` (an integer pointer). You declared `isSorted` to accept an `int` as its first argument. Looks like you just swapped the arguments around. You declared `isSorted` to take first argument size, second argument array, but you call it with the array first followed by size second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `int isSorted(int size, int array[])` which is saying that the first argument is an integer. Though later in the code you specify `int *sub_ordens = NULL;` which makes a pointer to an integer, but it is not itself an integer. To fix the first error you need to pass an integer to isSorted() instead of a pointer to an integer.

As for the second error, you did the opposite of what caused the first error. The `int array[]` is like saying `int *array` but you pass `int my_size;` which is an integer, not a pointer to an integer.

Stepping away from a technical aspect, let's think of this as something more tangible. You have two people, let's call them Person A and Person B. Person A holds a card with a number on it, Person B points to Person A, but Person B is not directly aware of the number written on the card. If the function wants a pointer, then you would look to Person B, but if it wants the number itself, you would look to Person A.

Your function is asking for a number (Person A) as the first parameter, and a pointer as the second parameter (Person B).

In the future, it would be easier to sort out if your code was a bit more uniform in presentation (spacing/style), and also if you remove the parts that are not directly related to the question.